# Which methods are best to analyse wave-packets?

Tags: nonlinear-analysis, functional-calculus, wavelets, wave-packets

I would like to find several methods to analyse wave-packets. My primary aim is to find a way to decompose wave-packets into "sub-wave packets" that, when subjected to some operation give the original wavepacket.

In other words, let a wave-packet be a bounded sequence $\{x_n\}$, and find a subsequence $\{y_n\}\in \{x_n\}$, which $A\{y_n\}=\{x_n\}$, where $A$ can be any linear or nonlinear functional. Then repeat the procedure to find n-th degree subsequence $\{y_n^{(n)}\} \in\{x_n\} $, which gives $A_n\{y_n^{(n)}\}=\{x_n\}$ where $A_n$ is any linear functional which $A:X\longrightarrow X$, where $X$ is a normed linear space, with elements $x,y,..=f(t),g(t)...$ where $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

For instance, the Fourier transform operator is such a functional, $A$, and gives a supersequence $\{y\}$ with $x=f(t)$, $$\{y\}_\omega=Ax=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt$$ of which $x=f(t) \in X$  .  Hence, $f(t)$ would be of interest.

My question is , if we have a nonlinear wavepacket, which methods are most suitable to construct such functionals? I have already tried Fourier transform and I am looking for alternative methods.

Thanks

PS: Update

From the given paper, I give an example of the measurement of "subharmonic" and "superharmonic" wave-packets in ocean waves due to sudden depth transition.

"We observe the generation of free second-order sub- and superharmonic wavepackets due to the sudden depth transition, in addition to changes to the main (first-order) wavepacket and its second-order bound waves. "

https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/surface-wavepackets-subject-to-an-abrupt-depth-change-part-2-experimental-analysis/1EEAF8FC7C7482B7E6551EEB529A67AD

This is an example of what I would like to extract from a wavepacket reading. But with which methods?

Thanks

Comment: A function is not a sequence, and the Fourier transform is not a sub-sequence of the original function. As ${\cal F}^*{\cal F}=I$, the Fourier-transform is also not an information losing or information reconstructing operation. You might find a closer example in the diverse compression schemes based on wavelet transforms. But there the subsequence and thus the reconstrution operator depends on the input signal, and the reconstruction is lossy, with the error also depending on the quality of the input signal.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that clarification. But what I mean is that a given function is converted into a sequence for analysis, since that can facilitate things, as the sequence can be bounded on an interval, or constructed on an interval. The loss of information may be acceptable, as long as it does not erase the wave-pattern itself.

Answer (score 1):

The situation for non-linear wavepackets is far more complex in general. Because the Fourier transform is a linear operator that preserves linearity, it is best suited for linear wavepackets. However, there are generalizations of Fourier transforms which are called short-time Fourier transforms.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform

These won't transform the entire time-dependent signal to its frequency spectrum like classical Fourier transform does; it will instead still have additionally information about time dependence of the signal after transformation. This is achieved by choosing an appropriate window function.

Nonlinear waves look in a short time interval like ordinary linear waves, so you might choose a window function around this small time interval and analyze frequency spectrum there.

The Gabor transform is also an example.

Comment: Thanks, I will leave this open for other answers, as your is a great answer of many possible. So I have given you thumb up, but for this reason did not accept it as a final answer.